# Spring + SOAP Generate XSD from XML with custom type objects

Tags: java, xml, soap, xsd, spring-ws

I'm working in SOAP WS using SPRING and could you please help me to generate XSD for the below required response soap xml.

Below is the current XSD

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"       xmlns="http://com/myws/webservices/accountservice" xmlns:account="http://myws.accessws.com/myWS"   targetNamespace="http://com/myws/webservices/accountservice" elementFormDefault="qualified">
<xsd:import namespace="http://webservice.com/myWS"  schemaLocation="AccountDetails.xsd"/>
<xsd:element name="AccountDetailsRequest">
    <xsd:complexType>
        <xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:element name="accountNumber" type="xsd:string"/>
            <xsd:element name="accountName" type="xsd:string"/>
            <xsd:element name="address" type="xsd:string"/>
            <xsd:element name="phone" type="xsd:string"/>
        </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:complexType>
</xsd:element>
<xsd:element name="AccountDetailsResponse">
    <xsd:complexType>
        <xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:element name="AccountDetails" type="account:Account"/>
        </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:complexType>
</xsd:element>
```

In the above xsd the response is set to Account object but i need to form a response xml in the below format and set it to the account object, as IN,VN,TYPE,LAST are all members of Account class (getters and setters).

```
<PERSON>
<IN>
<VN>1234567</VN>
<TYPE>A</TYPE>
<LAST>20150603</LAST>
</IN>
</PERSON>
```

I'm using the below code to set on the response for the current XSD

```
  AccountDetailsResponse response = new AccountDetailsResponse();
    /* call Spring injected service implementation to retrieve account data */
    Account account= accountService_i.getAccountDetails(request.getAccountNumber());
    response.setAccountDetails(account);
    return response;
```

Any help on this will be much appreciated

Thanks

Comment: xml to xsd using this [tool](http://www.freeformatter.com/xsd-generator.html). then you change according spring headers. otherwise you can use [jaxb](http://www.journaldev.com/1316/how-to-generate-xsd-from-java-class) generate your xsd.

Comment: Raghu, i'm using jaxb to generate classes from the xsd

Comment: what u need, generate XML from XSD?

Comment: I want to design xsd with IN,VN,TYPE,LAST and map it to account class. Eg: <xsd:element name="AccountDetails" type="account:Account"/> has to hold IN,VN,TYPE,LAST